# Dynamic DI in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, dependency-injection

I'm using asp.net core and I need to add DI dynamically like bellow:

```
services.AddTransient<SampleConfig>();

Assembly assembly = myAssembly;

if (assembly == null)
{
     return services;
}

foreach (var type in assembly.ExportedTypes)
{
     var interfaceType = type
        .GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name.Contains("IService")));

     if (interfaceType == null)
           continue;

     services.AddTransient(interfaceType, type);
}
```

My service is like this:

```
public PriceProvider(
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        SampleConfig config)
        : base(httpClientFactory, loggerFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        _c = config;
    }
```

My issue is everything works except SampleConfig.
It always is null.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You are registering interfaces only with your example code and it looks like `SampleConfig` is a class. Did you mean to register `SampleConfig` from settings/configuration? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for your comment, SampleConfig is a simple class, There is no issue registering a class in ServiceCollection. Anyway when I add my interface and service like this services.AddTransient(typeof([interfaceType]), typeof([serviceType])) everything is fine.

Comment: agreed, but that only registers the interface as target type to be injected. If I were to do `services.AddTransient<ISampleClass,SampleClass>()` and then try to inject/resolve `SampleClass` it would fail since only the interface was registered to be resolved

Comment: If `SampleClass` has a backing interface, then that is what should be used as the constructor argument/parameter. ie `ISampleClass config`

Comment: @Nkosi I tried this one but It's not working yet.